# Blazor wasm independent deployment error: Error parsing 'integrity' attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, blazor

I created an no host, progressive blazor WebAssembly application.

The URL rewrite module has been followed,Report an error after publishing：

```
Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('undefined'). The hash algorithm must be one of 'sha256', 'sha384', or 'sha512', followed by a '-' character.
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Content hash is required
    at e.<anonymous> (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
    at blazor.webassembly.js:1
    at Object.next (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
    at blazor.webassembly.js:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at blazor.webassembly.js:1
    at e.loadResourceWithCaching (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
    at e.loadResource (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
    at blazor.webassembly.js:1
    at l (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Content hash is required
    at e.<anonymous> (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
    at blazor.webassembly.js:1
    at Object.next (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
    at blazor.webassembly.js:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at blazor.webassembly.js:1
    at e.loadResourceWithCaching (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
    at e.loadResource (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
    at blazor.webassembly.js:1
    at l (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('undefined'). The hash algorithm must be one of 'sha256', 'sha384', or 'sha512', followed by a '-' character.
:52335/_framework/undefined:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
service-worker.js:15 Service worker: Install
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced same error, and that comment helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65470781/2358515

check `target framework` in Publish options - for client app it should be `browser-wasm`